# When using SLIME within Emacs: How do I reset the path to swank-loader.lisp?

Tags: emacs, lisp, common-lisp, slime, swank

After removing a distro installed version of SLIME, my MELPA (stable) installed SLIME version still insists on accessing the old system wide swank-loader.lisp.

How do I purge the system and reset the path to swank-loader.lisp

Comment: Maybe you’ll have more luck posting this to emacs.se

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on advise from the #LISP IRC channel (thank you user madrik). The following did in fact solve the problem:

```
sudo apt purge slime
```

Merely "removing" SLIME using `apt remove slime` was not enough, however purging the program did remove the configuration files and solved the problem.